# How to get Product review summery in a custom template file in Magento2?

Tags: template, custom, magento-2.1, ratings

I want to show star ratings in a custom phtml file. The product object is available inside that phtml file. How can I achieve the rating star summery there?

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below worked for me.

Below is the custom `.phtml` file:

```
// Define your $_helper object here

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_reviewFactory = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$_storeId = $_helper->getCurrentStoreId(); //Store ID;

?>

    <?php
// $_item is the product object

$_reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($_item, $_storeId);
$_ratingSummary = $_item->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$_reviewCount = $_item->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
//   var_dump($_item->getRatingSummary());
?>
<?php if ((int)$_ratingSummary > 0) : ?>
    <div class="product-reviews-summary short">
        <div class="rating-summary">
            <span class="label"><span>Rating:</span></span>

            <div title="<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
                <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>
                        %</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reviews-actions">
            <a href="#" class="action view">(<?php echo $_reviewCount; ?>)</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now In your custom helper class write the below code to get current store id:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function getCurrentStoreId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
}
```

This will return you the exact star rating div as in Magento 2 Luma theme.